# When does to_timestamp produce result from 19xx?

Tags: pyspark

Under what conditions/criteria does PySpark convert a date in the format `dd-MMM-yy` (01-JAN-40) to `1940-01-01 00:00:00.000` instead of `2040-01-01 00:00:00.000`?

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as psf
df.withColumn('my_date', psf.to_timestamp("my_date", "dd-MMM-yy"))
```

Some examples that I ran are below:

```
01-JAN-40 -> 1940-01-01 00:00:00.000
01-JAN-47 -> 1947-01-01 00:00:00.000
01-JAN-15 -> 2015-01-01 00:00:00.000
01-JAN-18 -> 2018-01-01 00:00:00.000
01-JAN-19 -> 2019-01-01 00:00:00.000
01-JAN-20 -> 2020-01-01 00:00:00.000
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently (Spark <= 2.4.4), spark is using the java `SimpleDateFormat` class under the hood to parse the string to date. From the java documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), it is specified that

> For parsing with the abbreviated year pattern ("y" or "yy"), SimpleDateFormat must interpret the abbreviated year relative to some century. It does this by adjusting dates to be within 80 years before and 20 years after the time the SimpleDateFormat instance is created.

So if you run it in 2019, everything up to 39 is going to be in 20xx and everything else will be in 19xx